# Variable tests in /etc/profile

Tags: linux, bash

Please help to interpret the meaning of the following test, from `/etc/profile`:

`if [ "${PS1-}" ]...`

Does it mean that even if `PS1` is not set, the `-` will be returned causing always `true` part of `if` statement to be executed?

Comment: The code is buggy, full-stop. Needs quotes, `[ "${PS1-}" ]`, to be correct; without them, an arbitrary number of `test` predicates can result from the expansion (unless, perhaps, the question is mistagged, and it's really zsh rather than bash in use).

Comment: ...since this is effectively a "what does this buggy code do?" question, providing an answer would involve delving into the details of the bug, and is not practicable at all.

Comment: ...and no, the `-` is not a constant suffix. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: ...for a hint on _why_ the `-` suffix can be useful without any values following it, see [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112), on `set -u` / `set -o nounset`, particularly the "Rewriting scripts to deal with it" section at the end.